# how to set footer at bottom of expandablelist?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, footer

I have used expandablelist and I want to set its footer at bottom of the screen but its not working. I have attached its codes and screenshot.

```
 <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ExpandableListView>

expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("footer");
        expListView.addFooterView(textView);
```

[image]

**EDITTED**

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
                                     List<String> listDataHeader,
                                     HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,
                    childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
            txtListChild.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }
            // changing the +/- on expanded list view
            TextView txt_plusminus = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.plus_txt);
            if (isExpanded) {
                txt_plusminus.setText("-");
                Drawable plusDrawable = getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more);
                plusDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);             txt_plusminus.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.btn_dropdown, 0, 0, 0);
                txt_plusminus.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, plusDrawable, null);
//                txt_plusminus.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,plusDrawable,null);
            } else {
                txt_plusminus.setText("+");
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            // lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
            lblListHeader.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.black));

            // nav drawer icons from resources
            // navMenuIcons =
            // getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
            // imgListGroup.setImageDrawable(navMenuIcons.getDrawable(groupPosition));

            // adding icon to expandable list view
            ImageView imgListGroup = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ic_txt);
            imgListGroup.setImageResource(SubMenuActivity.icon[groupPosition]);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: `Footer` view will get add after last item of list . So this is the expected output of `addFooterView()`. If you need View to exist always in Bottom you can use a `View` with alignment at bottom outside of `ListView`. Or with `Footer View` approach you can make you `ListView`  to fill the height so that it will give same appearance.

Answer (score 4):

You can add footer in your list by using below code:

```
View v= inflator.inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);
expandableList.addFooterView(v);
```

Comment: Please set adapter also by which you can able to see footer view.

Comment: expandableList.setAdapter(new ExpanadableListAdapter());

Comment: I have also added its adapter and still same problem

Comment: Note that the layout you use for the footer view should not be an empty layout; just add a View for whatever height you need.

Answer (score 0):

Look into below code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ExpandableListView list = findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        TextView v = new TextView(this);
        v.setText("Footer");
        list.addFooterView(v);
        list.setAdapter(new ExpanadableListAdapter());
    }

    class ExpanadableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```